# Multiple Return Types from Function based on Input?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing this in Typescript in an Angular Application.

Suppose I have a interface:

```
export interface a{
 name: string;
 address: string;
}
```

I have a function in service which should return a[ ] or a, based on input condition:

```
public getDetails(uid?: number):Observable<a[]> | Observable<a>{
    if(uid){
        return this.httpClient.get(`server-address/a/uid`) as Observable<a>
    }
    else{
        return this.httpClient.get(`server-address/a`) as Observable<a[]>
    }
}
```

This obviously errors out that same function cannot return two things. Any way return multiple items based on input? Any better way to do it?

Comment: *"This obviously errors out that same function cannot return two things."* - that's not obvious, a function can certainly return one of two things. What's the specific error? What's `a`? Give a [mre].

Comment: is it compulsory to return as type "a"? if you return as any type then you may achieve your goal

Comment: @Parth they shouldn't need a type assertion here _at all_, `as any` is basically giving up on types entirely.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that this method should probably have [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), so the consumer doesn't always have to check whether the observable is of `a` or `a[]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, In the component when calling the function from service, it would give error, `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. No overload matches this call.` . However, implementing Amir's solution (Method Overloading) works wonderfully in my case, no more complains :D
Thank you so much for the hints and the suggestion of Overloads !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is fine. A function can return more than 1 type based on certain conditions. This is completely acceptable.

Any better way to do it? Yes, you can take advantage of method overloading. Here is an example

```
public getDetails(uid: number):Observable<a>;
public getDetails():Observable<a[]>;
public getDetails(uid?: number):Observable<a[]> | Observable<a>{
    if(uid){
        return this.httpClient.get(`server-address/a/uid`) as Observable<a>
    }
    return this.httpClient.get(`server-address/a`) as Observable<a[]>
}
```

With the above overloads, your IDE will give you hints about the output based on the input.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution!! Works wonderfully, no more complains from the compiler/IDE :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a generic approach, but would suit this particular case you have included

```
export interface A{
 name: string;
 address: string;
}

function getDetails():A;
function getDetails(uid:number):A[];

function getDetails(uid?:number):A|A[]{
    if(uid){
        return {} as A;
    }else{
        return [] as A[];
    }
}


const t1=getDetails();
const t2=getDetails(4);
```

t1 and t2 are correcty recognized as A and A[] accordingly.
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBSHwMgdBRkZI9FAVADeikGDGQ%20WuqEonGYAG42QxuNwiQVubyBYoAL7BZJcWCoCjwLzMSCoAAi6oYWMEAAoAJT5CqC%20XmJUqrTqrWoHXQfXsCjcfKcdiIaQ-I0VADaAF1BYozYrlarrdrdXrHdwAPwut0eshegA%20Pt9rJKJURkadBvTGfzTgJZC8zOlYmEJrZGelMEEkDz%20ZKhcJXj95cqfsF%20dlsuCCE4ghoqAAjABeNWa8P2w2C-uDtAAJnHYdtEYALAaAyocA0PMXQIhqc4Qewh-dGHz2Aw1fxYNB1IkGCC9CIvAAiACiqw5NX0b6SOJvuADioAA5MIABykASG%20QQqAA8t8ZC7HW-ATtyjgKK40h4KATiHjooxYPoKAIIgMLCFc3ySNS0QiAYHA4t0LBsFw3BBCUQA)

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, works wonderfully. Learnt about Method Overloading today :)